# Declaration of Decision variables and equations in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

In my Power Control Cptimization problem I have only power vector P(I) as decision variable. However, it involves in the calculation of SINR and system total power thus,  my question is: do I need to declar SINR and system total power as variables cause they include P(I) or it is sufficient to put only P(I) in variables and the system will change everything based on it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to declare the other arrays as variables. If they are calculated from the power vector, their values will change according to how the power vector's values are adjusted inside the solver.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was worried if that i might declar it in a bad way. thankyou for the confirmation really.